# How should I use controller as syntax with angular directives?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say for example I have this controller:

```
    function MainController() {

         var self = this;

         self.employee = {
             name: 'Travis Libby',
             occupation: 'Frontend Engineer'
         };

    }
```

And I have defined this directive:

```
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('employeeCard', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'AEC',
                template: '<strong>{{ main.employee.name }}</strong>'
            }
    });
```

And my html:

```
    <body ng-controller="MainController as main">

        <employee-card></employee-card>

    </body>
```

By using controller as syntax, I now have to reference the alias of my controller inside the directive itself. Doesn't that pattern destroy the point of custom directives? How would I then use this custom directive inside any other controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is use isolated scope and pass in `employee`

```
<employee-card employee="main.employee"></employee-card>
```

JS

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('employeeCard', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {employee :'='},
            template: '<strong>{{ employee.name }}</strong>'
        }
});
```